# Debian/Arch audio output not correctly after or before a restart

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

While I was using Debian 9 / Latest Arch Linux, If my headphones are plugged in before I halt the PC, next time I boot up my PC, whether the earphone was plugged in or not, the startup audio will always output to earphone.

How can I do to let the audio output through speakers if the earphones are not plugged in while booting up?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it easier to understand by avoiding using double-negatives?

Comment: Sorry for that, already edited.